# Using Groups, drop duplicated NaNs only

Tags: python, pandas

With my data grouped by Assay, Image and Roi, for each group I wish to delete all but the first rows which have a NaN value in the 'Intensity' column.

My attempt is able to delete duplicates, but this isn't specific to NaN values.

```
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = DataFrame({'assay':['cnt']*11,
                'image':['001']*10+['002'],
                'roi':['1']*5+['2']*5+['3'],
                'dist':[99,90,50,2,30,65,95,30,56,5,33],
                'cellArea':[99,90,50,2,30,65,95,30,56,5,33],
                'xy':np.fabs(np.random.randn(11)*100),
                'intensity':[88,88,1,3,67,67,67,95,1,3,2]},
               columns=['assay','image','roi','dist','xy','cellArea','intensity','adjacency'])
df.loc[df.intensity < 10, ['intensity','xy']] = np.nan
df
```

[image]

```
df.groupby(['assay','image','roi']).apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates(['intensity'], keep='first'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `drop_duplicates` you can pass the `duplicated & is.null` checker into the lambda function as:

```
df.groupby(['assay','image','roi']).apply(lambda x: x.loc[~(x.duplicated(['intensity']) & x.intensity.isnull())])
```